# using GeoIP on Haproxy

Tags: proxy, geoip, haproxy

How do I connect to the database geoip Haproxy?

an example.
Haproxy decides at ip country and city, and modifies http headers for transmission to the backends:

```
reqadd      X-Country:\ Country
```

Answer (score -1):

I think what you want is something you should look for in a dynamic dns, like route53 where it can detect the ip and route to the closest load balancer.  You can however setup acl requests in haproxy.  More in section 7 of the man pages: http://haproxy.1wt.eu/download/1.5/doc/configuration.txt